# How to get key and value in foreach

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, magento2.2

I have create a knockout template ....
How to get key and value from foreach in this template...

```
 <!-- ko foreach: { data: getCouponCodes(), as: 'key => value' } -->
```

I need to get key and value

[image]

Comment: What key and value? Is `'key => value'` supposed to be PHP code? Show a meaningful sample of data, your viewmodel, explain what currently happens and what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: 0:{ name : "john" } 1: {name : "paul"}. I want to get the values of 'name ' and 'john'

Comment: And the data is ... where? Again, post your code.

Comment: Please post your *code*. Not a badly cropped screenshot without any context. Post a working viewmodel. Actual code. Read [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If `getCouponCodes` returns an array of objects, there's no "special" knockout way of getting the key(s) and value(s) of those objects directly in the binding.

In other words: you'll have to use plain javascript in either your view or viewmodel. There are many possible solutions, here are two to get you started:

### Preferred: use a `computed` to transform the data to the desired format:

```js
const getCouponCodes = () => [ { name: "John" }, { name: "Kevin" } ]

ko.applyBindings({ 
  couponData: ko.pureComputed(() =>
    // Use whatever logic you require to return a viewmodel of "key" and "value"
    getCouponCodes()
      .reduce(
        // You can also use: `for ... in`, `Object.keys`, etc.
        //  search for "Iterate over js object" to learn more
        (data, coupon) => data.concat(Object.entries(coupon)),
        []
      )
      // Here we construct a simple viewmodel to make our data-binds easier
      .map(([k, v]) => ({ key: k, value: v }))
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: couponData -->

<div data-bind="text: key + ': ' + value"></div>

<!-- /ko -->
```

### Alternative Use `Object.keys` and `$parent` directly in your view

```js
ko.applyBindings({ 
  getCouponCodes: () => [ { name: "John" }, { name: "Kevin" } ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: getCouponCodes() -->

<!-- ko foreach: Object.keys($data) -->

<div data-bind="text: $data + ': ' + $parent[$data]"></div>

<!-- /ko -->

<!-- /ko -->
```