# How do I map data with nested dictionaries?

Tags: javascript, razor, knockout.js

I use KO JS and had an issue with displaying keys of the root keys. I asked a question about it and did have some progress but still, problem is not solved.
[LINK TO PREVIOUS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72295598/how-to-access-nested-elements-in-array-from-the-front-end-using-knockout-js)

I figured that my data needed mapping. Data that I get from back-end looks like this :
[image]

Here is text version of sample data

```
"Pricings": {
        "2021-22": {
            "Tbilisi": {
                "PriceHeaders": [
                  
                ],
                "Comment": "TBi",
                "Pricings": [
                    {
                        
                    }
                ]
        },
        "2020-21": {
            "Tbilisi": {
                "PriceHeaders": [
                   
                ],
                "Comment": "TBi",
                "Pricings": [
                    {
                       
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
}
```

I'm thinking about recreating data like this :
from :

```
2020-21 :
{
    Tbilisi: {PriceHeaders: Array(9), Comment: 'TBi', Pricings: Array(1)}
}
```

To :

```
Year : 2020-21 
Cities : {
    Tbilisi: {PriceHeaders: Array(9), Comment: 'TBi', Pricings: Array(1)}
}
```

After that, I can run a simple foreach and get Values of **Year** and Any key from **Cities**.

I came up with something like this

```
Object.entries(data).map(([year, cities]) =>
(
    {
     "year": year,
     "cities": Object.entries(cities).map(([name, cities]) =>
      (
          {
              name,
              ...cities
          }
      ))
     }
 ))
```

Problem is, I can not make use of this code in data bind

```
        <div data-bind="data : THIS FUNCTION HERE , as 'result'"></div>
```

Comment: Please reference the original question you asked

Comment: What the heck will we do with screenshot of data. Paste copiable object.

Comment: @Greg I think your original question is more relevant, and they ask about more or less the same issue
This is an example of how you can achieve what you want without changing your original data structure
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681015/how-to-get-key-and-value-in-foreach

Comment: @ViniciusCardoso Dude that's OP's original question

Comment: @ViniciusCardoso that is my initial question that led to this question

Comment: @ScottAnderson I'll try to apply it. Thanks

Comment: @ScottAnderson I looked at the solution and I do not understand how it would work with dynamic data. In my case, Key names will change all the time and I will need a way to access root key and keys inside of it

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been solved already with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681015/how-to-get-key-and-value-in-foreach)

The key code is:

```
.reduce(
        // You can also use: `for ... in`, `Object.keys`, etc.
        //  search for "Iterate over js object" to learn more
        (data, coupon) => data.concat(Object.entries(coupon)),
        []
      )
      // Here we construct a simple viewmodel to make our data-binds easier
      .map(([k, v]) => ({ key: k, value: v }))
```

What this will do for your data is wrap the data you have already in a wrapper object, so with your example data it would compose...

```
{
    key: "2020-21",
    value: {
        Tbilisi: {
            PriceHeaders: Array(9), Comment: 'TBi', Pricings: Array(1)
        }
    }
}
```

...from your original structure

```
2020-21 :
{
    Tbilisi: {PriceHeaders: Array(9), Comment: 'TBi', Pricings: Array(1)}
}
```

This means that when you iterate over the pureComputed function in your kojs template, you will be able to access year with `[binding]: key` and the nested data with `[binding: value`

You may also want to look into the ['mapping' plugin](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) in knockout for the object values, to make it update when data is changed (unless it will always be static)